# Search A between B in ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-templates

I tried to search a local manager from zipcode A to zipcode B.

For example:

```
"Manager west" as the regions
zipform | zipto
17000  to 17259
17300  to 19309
19360  to 19419
23920  to 23999
```

**models.py**

```
class Region(models.Model):
    zipfrom = models.CharField(u'PLZ von', max_length=50, blank=True)
    zipto = models.CharField(u'PLZ bis', max_length=50, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Region'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Regionen'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0} - {1}".format(self.zipfrom, self.zipto)


class AddPartner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length=50)
    regionen = models.ManyToManyField(Region, verbose_name=u'regionen', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'AddPartner'
        verbose_name_plural = u'AddPartners'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, render_to_response 
from django.template import Template, RequestContext
from partner.models import AddPartner, Region
from django.db.models import Q

def partnerview(request):
    partner = AddPartner.objects.all()
    region = Region.objects.all()   
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']: 
        q = request.GET['q']
        suche = region.filter(Q(zipto=q) | Q(zipform=q)) # despair
    else:
        return render_to_response('partner.html',{
        'partner': partner, 'region': region, },context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 

    return render_to_response('partner.html',{
        'partner': partner, 'region': region,'suches': suche, 'query': q
    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am a beginner and I have no idea to handle this. The next big question is to get the rigt result "the local manager" in the template.

Comment: Is `q = request.GET['q']` here a zip code? And you are trying to find what `Region` that zipcode is from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pair of `__lte`/`__gte` lookups. The next query will find the regions where `zipfrom <= q <= zipto`:

```
suche = region.filter(zipfrom__lte=q, zipto__gte=q)
```

To get the list of managers for found regions use the following query:

```
managers = AddPartner.objects.distinct().filter(regionen__in=suche)
```

Comment: It doesn't work 100%. I get always 2 matches. For example Search: **14469**, the Result is **1000 - 1939**  and **14400 - 16949** the second one is right the first not.

Comment: It works 100% - this is how string comparison works.  So you have to convert the zip fields to `IntegerField` or store the short zip codes as `01000` and `01939`.